# Wifi problems - stops responding

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have problem with my WiFi. When I turn on my PC, everything is going fine, but in some time, My WiFi stops responding and connection is lost. After aprox. 1 minute is connection back, but it's really annoying (even when I'm playing online and it kicks me out of server because of this). When it happens, with my signal icon appears orange triangle with exclamation mark and it stops working as I said, about one minute. After that triangle disappear and connection is again back.

This fault is not regular, it is going to randomly. I tried to reinstall network drivers, it didn't helped.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which models of computer and wireless router are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, and I have PC build by myself and router is Huawei HG622U also I have Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter.

Comment: Of course, I have more wireless devices at home like mobiles and other computers/notebooks, but this issue is appearing only on my computer, nowhere else.